# Does location update remain running after force close app

Tags: ios, iphone, cllocationmanager

I am sending user location at n time on server for tracking. Working fine in foreground and background mode. But my question is bit more theoretical.. Does my location update service remain running after i force close the app on the device?

I know i can check it on server, But sorry i don't have server access permission. So i have to be sure in which scenario my location service will stop running.

Comment: No, the app will not be able to send the request to server after app is closed.

Comment: Thanx @YogeshSuthar for the reply, appreciate it.

Comment: In some circumstances, the app can run in background, even the app is force closed, iOS will restart your app but the app should come in apple's criteria like VOIP else your app will get rejected by appstore.

Comment: I have registered my app for background uploading and location updating. And app is also uploaded on the app store.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar but my main concern is that i want to make sure that is my location update will stop if app will be force closed.

Comment: Dilip, as I said iOS will restart your app after it get force closed, so location update service will also start. Does your app get approved by appstore?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Yes it has been approved.. But my client complain that location service does not updating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep it will continue to be updated when the application is sent into the background. For some official docs check [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10) under the "Getting Location Events in the Background (iOS Only)" section.

Also, under special circumstances you can register your application to have a true background process running like Android allows. So when the user kills the background application, your app doesn't really die. The background process continues to work. Apple will only allow apps that have a necessary reason for this though. Such as a turn by turn navigation app (example from the docs).

Comment: Thanx for reply.. Can you suggest me link for second option?

Comment: check out this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24 under the "Background Execution and Multitasking" section and click the "Implementing long running background tasks" link

Comment: I am using this in my app, But this says "`Location updates
location
The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background.`" And my app uploading the location in background mode. It does not suggest that app will upload location after user force close the app.

Comment: I believe my previous comment was a bit misleading. If you read the first sentence in the section specified in the link from my original answer it says `iOS supports the delivery of location events to apps that are __suspended__ or __no longer running__.`. 

For iOS an application is put into the background when you click the home button. If it has no other tasks to complete it will soon be suspended when it tells the OS that it is done. If it has something to do, such as a background task, it asks the OS for a bit more time to finish up before it is suspended.

Comment: AFAIK in iOS 7 if you doubleclick the home button and swipe your app up and away, its gone. Guaranteed. This is equivalent to going into App manager in Android and clicking "Stop tasks" or "Stop service". 

In terms of location services, if you click home, your app goes into background state. If you have stuff to do, you can tell the OS you need a short or a long time. But with location services you can subscribe to events that will "wake up" your app to give it the new location data. It wont launch the app, but it will take your app from suspended to background state. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok thanx for clarification. So i have clicked the home twice and than swipe up the app, Than my location service wont work. Only if i send application to background using single tap on home it will work, Is this correct.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if the application is removed from background then location update will be stopped.

Comment: Thanx for reply. Do you know any document that saying that this will happen. it will be help.

Answer (score 1):

iOS will only restart an app after a force close if its uses region monitoring or the significant-change location service. From the iOS Location and Maps Programming Guide section on [Getting the User’s Location](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10):

> If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the system doesn’t automatically restart your app when new location updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or the significant-change location service.

iOS only restarts the app if it has Background App Refresh enabled:

> when a user disables the Background App Refresh setting either globally or specifically for your app, the system doesn’t relaunch your app for any location events, including significant-change or region monitoring events.